# I already installed firebase and the error remains

Tags: firebase

src\firebaseConnection.js
Line 17:17:  'initializeApp' is not defined  no-undef

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.

webpack compiled with 1 error and 1 warning
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p4ctM.jpg)

Comment: Please refrain from posting screenshots. Post the code and error stack directly into your question instead.

Answer (score 0):

You should import like this:

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";

const firebaseConfig = {...};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
```

---

You may want to visit this [documentation](https://Add%20Firebase%20to%20your%20JavaScript%20project) and learn how to use Firebase Services such as Firestore.